# Cambiar el color de <option> elegida en <select>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un `select` llamado "prioridad" que tiene 3 opciones: alta, media y baja.

Me gustaría que cuando se seleccione alta, me ponga el nombre "alta" en rojo, "media" en amarillo y "baja" en verde. Así en mi vista, me saldrá mi lista de prioridades con los nombres: alta, media, baja en estos 3 colores para poder visualizar rápidamente que prioridades son mas importantes que otras.

Código del `select`:

```
<% form.select :prioridad, ["alta", "media", "baja"], id: : tarea_prioridad %>
```

Lo que pretendo hacer, pero así no lo logro, es lo siguiente:

```
<% form.select :prioridad, ["alta", {syle=>color:"red"},"media",{syle=>color:"green"}, "baja",{syle=>color:"yellow"}], id: : tarea_prioridad %>
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código actual de tu forma indicando cuáles son los elementos que quieres que cambien de color? Si vas a guardar la selección en la BD, podrías utilizar AJAX para que el cambio se vea inmediato.

Comment: Hola, lo que tengo es esto: <%form.select :prioridad, ["alta", "media", "baja"], id: : tarea_prioridad%> y lo que pretendo hacer, pero que asi no lo logro es lo siguiente <%form.select :prioridad, ["alta", {syle=>color:"red"},"media",{syle=>color:"green"}, "baja",{syle=>color:"yellow"}], id: : tarea_prioridad%>. Alguna idea sin hacerlo demasiado complicado?

Comment: eso lo puedes hacer con javascript..

Comment: me puedes indicar como porfavor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo unos cuantos detalles:

- Estás usando `syle` en vez de `style`, que es el nombre correcto del atributo.
- Sin embargo, en vez de usar `style`, deberías delegar en `class` tus estilos, que es la forma correcta de separar estructura (html) de estilo (css).
- Inicias tu línea con `<%` en vez de `<%=` que es lo usado cuando se retorna un valor al template.
- `id: : tarea_prioridad` es innecesario, ya que si tu objeto es `tarea` y el atributo es `prioridad`, automáticamente te va a generar `id="tarea_prioridad"` cuando renderices el template.
- Deberías usar [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) en vez de un arreglo como parámetro de `select`, ya que dicho método permite personalizar los elementos `<option>` que contendrá tu `<select>`.

La línea a usar debería ser algo como:

```
 <%= form.select :prioridad, options_for_select([["alta", {class: 'high'}],["media",{class: 'middle'}], ["baja",{class: 'low'}]]) %>
```

Luego debes agregar los estilos en tu css, que terminaría dándote un html como el descrito abajo:

```css
.low {
  color: green;
}

.middle {
  color: yellow;
}

.high {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select name="tarea[prioridad]" id="tarea_prioridad">
  <option class="high" value="alta">alta</option>
  <option class="middle" value="media">media</option>
  <option class="low" value="baja">baja</option>
</select>
```

Toma en consideración que los `<option>` [son renderizados de distinta forma por cada S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7208814/895789), por lo cual las opciones para darle estilo son limitadas.
Si necesitas mayor control sobre el estilo de los `<option>`, ya deberías usar librerías JS como [`select2`](https://select2.org/) o [`chosen`](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Comment: Gracias Alter, efectivamente así tiene más sentido. Sin embargo no me coje los colores. Debe ser que "algo" de mi hoja de estilos lo está bloqueando. Tengo que descubrir que és. Y una vez lo encuentre así tiene que funcionar. Gracias.

Comment: @mantisa ¿incluso te sale mal con el código ejecutable [que agregué en la respuesta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m56BP.png)? Yo estoy usando Chrome en Linux, no se si tenga que ver que tú puedas estar usando otro S.O./explorador, pero así como está debería funcionar. Saludos

Comment: Si, incluso con tu codigo. Yo utilizo Ubuntu. Pero como te digo, debe ser algo de mi hoja de estilos lo que lo bloquea. Aun no he descubierto que es...