# Estilos en options (Safari)

Tags: css, angular, select, safari, options

No consigo que el navegador Safari me coja los estilos que le doy a unos options.

Mi código es este:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="options">
                <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.nombre" [style.background-color]="item.recomendado ? '#346ba3' : 'black'">{{item.nombre}}
                </option>
              </select>
```

En el resto de navegadores funciona sin problema, pero en Safari no. ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Esta misma pregunta ya se ha realizado en el sitio: [¿como cambiar los colores por defecto de los options de un select?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48671/250) o [Cambiar el color de <option> elegida en <select>](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/173117/250). La respuesta básica es: no hay solución... o al menos no hay una que te vaya a servir en todos los navegadores en general, o en Safari en particular. En el estándar no se especifica nada sobre los `option` y cada navegador los implementa a su manera (y ya en móvil ni hablamos).